# How to Compress a Folder That Changes name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, rar, winrar

I'm trying to compress a folder that changes name.

Example:

```
C:\202004
C:\202005
C:\202006
C:\202007
```

It keep creating a new folder as the months keep going by.

I wanna compress only the folder correspondent to the current month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get some help from `powershell`'s `Get_date` command:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format "yyyyMM"}"') do if exist "C:\%%a" echo C:\%%a
```

Where you would replace `echo C:\%%a` with your actual compression command.

a better method would be if you can test for the latest created folder and then compress that folder only.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "c:\20*" /b /ad /o-d') do set "latest=%%i" & goto :comp
:comp
echo Zip/7z/rar "c:\%latest%" here
```

Or we can combine the above by find the latest folder, then test if it is corresponding to the month, only then compress it:

```
@echo off
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "c:\20*" /b /ad /o-d') do set "latest=%%i" & goto :comp
:comp
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format "yyyyMM"}"') do if "%%a" == "%latest%" echo Zip/7z/Rar C:\%latest% here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have powershell 5+

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"
Compress-Archive -Path "c:\$date\" -DestinationPath "c:\$date.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already selected an answer. It might be good to be able to compress a directory outside of the current month. This code will compress all of them if an archive file does not exist. By default, it will only compress the current month.

=== Compress-MonthlyFiles.ps1

```
#Requires -Version 5
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$AllMonths = $false
)

$BaseDir = 'C:\src\t'
$CompDir = 'C:\src\t\Compressed\Months'
$DirFilter = if ($AllMonths) { '??????' } else { Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMM'}

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $BaseDir -Filter $DirFilter |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Check to see that the directory name is exactly six (6) digits
        if ($_.Name -match '^\d{6}$') {
            $ArchiveFilename = Join-Path -Path $CompDir -ChildPath "$($_.Name).zip"
            # If the archive file does not exist, create it
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ArchiveFilename)) {
                Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath $ArchiveFilename
            }
        }
    }
```

Invoke it to compress only the current month using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File .\Compress-MonthlyFiles.ps1
```

Make archive files for all months if they do not already exist using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File .\Compress-MonthlyFiles.ps1 -AllMonths
```